# When object property is not defined then console.log(obj.property) gives "undefined", why?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Lets say we have,

```js
    var obj = {
      name: "AKS"
    };
    console.log(obj.name);
    console.log(obj.lname);
```

Output:

> ```
>      AKS
>      undefined
> ```

Where else if we do:

```js
var func = function() {
  var name = "AKS";
};
console.log(name);
```

Output:

> ```
> error: name is not defined
> ```

1. In first snippet, obj property lname is not defined. Then why it
   doesn't throw error?
2. In second snippet, name is not defined in
   function scope, nor its in global scope. Hence the error is
   expected.

What is the basic difference between the two?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Finally I found the answer.
_When interpreter finds an object trying to access a property( `newObj.prop`), it first looks if the property is directly defined over the object or not. If not found, it looks up to Prototype object. If it finds there it retruns the value else returns `undefined`_

Answer (score 1):

That's the way the behaviour is defined. If you access an undefined *property on an object*, it returns the value `undefined`. But if you try to use a *locally defined symbol name* (a.k.a. a variable) which does not exist, i.e. has never been defined, that's an error.

Why the language designer decided that testing for the existence of a property would best be done by trying to access the property is anyone's guess. However, non-existent variables throwing an error is very standard behaviour across languages.

Note that the undefined property behaviour does not work on all types. Most notably you cannot access properties on `undefined`, it will produce an error. So `foo.bar.baz` where `bar` is `undefined` will produce an error.

Comment: In javascript it doesn't go that way. If "use strict"; is not used, then, when read operation is performed on not declared variable then it throws error, however, if write operation is performed on not declared variable then this variable will be placed in global scope and write operation will be performed on the variable.

Comment: There's also the `in` operator.

Comment: @Aks, gca Yes, there are a thousand caveats to more detailed behaviour… However, I'm not going to recite the entire ECMAScript specification and all usage patterns here.

Answer (score -1):

If you use strict mode, it can give you error then object is [sealed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) or [frozen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

Comment: I understand this, but i want to understand the behaviour here. Thanks